# Batch FOR /f nested loops looking for match in file2 against each line in file1

Tags: file, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I have two files with serial numbers. I need to see if any of the serial numbers in file 1 exist in file 2 and output them to file 3.

This is not working. Help.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f %%i in (CiscoSerialNumbers.txt) do (
    for /f %%j in (UCSSerialNumbers.txt) do (
        if %%i==%%j (
            echo %%j >> SerialNumbersMatch.txt
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: How is your  code not working? Be more precise!

Comment: Sample data of `*SerialNumbers.txt` could also be helpful...

Comment: The serial number files just have serial numbers in them one per line like FTX90365278
FTZ45672987

etc... Here is the output with echo on

C:\Work>SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

C:\Work>for /F %i in (CiscoSerialNumbers.txt) do (for /F %j in (UCSSerialNumbers.txt) do (if %i == %j (echo %j ) ) )

Comment: Hmmm, seems I don't know how to format a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /l /x /g:CiscoSerialNumbers.txt UCSSerialNumbers.txt > SerialNumbersMatch.txt
```

This will search the file `UCSSerialNumbers.txt` for literal (`/l`) values contained matching exactly (`/x`) elements contained in `CiscoSerialNumbers.txt`, sending the output to `SerialNumbersMatch.txt`